# Get tab's elemet in background.js

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

In my chrome extension I want to get the value of input like:

**background.js:**

```
chrome.downloads.onCreated.addListener(
    function foo(e) {
        var address = document.getElementById("server-adrress").value;
        console.log(address );
    }
);
```

**Options.html**

```
...
<input id="server-adr-txt" type="text" placeholder="Server Address">
```

But I'm getting the error:

> Error in event handler: TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

In this line:

```
var address = document.getElementById("server-adrress").value;
```

Comment: is the options.html is the user interface of your chrome extension or the webpage which on our chrome extension needs to run?

Comment: @Tharun208 In manifest file I have `"options_page": "Options.html"`, that's a settings page that I created

Comment: usually backgroud.js works with the user interface of our chrome extension and for your script to work, we need to add script to our options.html page.

Comment: @Tharun208 Ok, I will try go that way

Comment: I succeded with `chrome.storage.sync.get`